# How can I keep concatenated tokens separate during lexing when a more general token is availible

Tags: antlr, token, lexer, greedy

The language I'm working on allows certain tokens to be stuck together (eg "intfloat") and I'm looking for a way to have the lexer not turn them into an ID so they're available separately at parse time.  The simplest grammar I can come up with that demonstrates it is (WS omitted):

```
B: 'B';
C: 'C';
ID: ('a'..'z')+;
doc : (B | C | ID)* EOF;
```

Run against:

```
bc
abc
bcd
```

What I'd like out of the lexer:

```
B C
ID (starts with not-a-keyword so it's an ID)
<error> (cannot concat non-keywords)
```

But what I get is 3 IDs, as expected.

I have been looking at making the ID not greedy but that degenerates into individual tokens for each character.  I suppose I could glue them back together later, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start towards a solution, using the lexer to break up the text into tokens. The trick here is that rule `ID` can emit more than one token per invokation. This is non-standard lexer behavior so there are some caveats:

- I'm confident that this *won't* work in ANTLR4.
- This code assumes all tokens are queued into `tokenQueue`.
- Rule `ID` doesn't prevent a keyword from repeating, so `intintint` produces tokens `INT` `INT` `INT`. If that's bad, you'll want to handle that either on the lexer or parser side, depending on which makes more sense in your grammar.
- The shorter the keyword, the more fragile this solution becomes. Input `internal` is an invalid `ID` because it starts with keyword `int` but is followed by a non-keyword string.
- The grammar produces warnings that I haven't expunged. If you use this code, I recommend attempting to remove them.

Here is the grammar:

#### MultiToken.g

```
grammar MultiToken;


@lexer::members{
    private java.util.LinkedList<Token> tokenQueue = new java.util.LinkedList<Token>();

    @Override
    public Token nextToken() {
            Token t = super.nextToken();
            if (tokenQueue.isEmpty()){
                if (t.getType() == Token.EOF){
                    return t;
                } else { 
                    throw new IllegalStateException("All tokens must be queued!");
                }
            } else { 
                return tokenQueue.removeFirst();
            }
    }

    public void emit(int ttype, int tokenIndex) {
        //This is lifted from ANTLR's Lexer class, 
        //but modified to handle queueing and multiple tokens per rule.
        Token t;

        if (tokenIndex > 0){
            CommonToken last = (CommonToken) tokenQueue.getLast();
            t = new CommonToken(input, ttype, state.channel, last.getStopIndex() + 1, getCharIndex() - 1);
        } else { 
            t = new CommonToken(input, ttype, state.channel, state.tokenStartCharIndex, getCharIndex() - 1);
        }

        t.setLine(state.tokenStartLine);
        t.setText(state.text);
        t.setCharPositionInLine(state.tokenStartCharPositionInLine);
        emit(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void emit(Token t){
        super.emit(t);
        tokenQueue.addLast(t);
    }
}

doc     : (INT | FLOAT | ID | NUMBER)* EOF;

fragment
INT     : 'int';

fragment
FLOAT   : 'float';

NUMBER  : ('0'..'9')+;

ID  
@init {
    int index = 0; 
    boolean rawId = false;
    boolean keyword = false;
}
        : ({!rawId}? INT {emit(INT, index++); keyword = true;}
            | {!rawId}? FLOAT {emit(FLOAT, index++); keyword = true;}
            | {!keyword}? ('a'..'z')+ {emit(ID, index++); rawId = true;} 
          )+
        ;

WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();};
```

---

#### Test Case 1: Mixed Keywords

*Input*

```
intfloat a
int b
float c
intfloatintfloat d
```

*Output (Tokens)*

```
[INT : int] [FLOAT : float] [ID : a] 
[INT : int] [ID : b]
[FLOAT : float] [ID : c] 
[INT : int] [FLOAT : float] [INT : int] [FLOAT : float] [ID : d]
```

#### Test Case 2: Ids containing Keywords

*Input*

```
aintfloat
bint
cfloat
dintfloatintfloat
```

*Output (Tokens)*

```
[ID : aintfloat] 
[ID : bint] 
[ID : cfloat] 
[ID : dintfloatintfloat]
```

#### Test Case 3: Bad Id #1

*Input*

```
internal
```

*Output (Tokens & Lexer Error)*

```
[INT : int] [ID : rnal] 
line 1:3 rule ID failed predicate: {!keyword}?
```

#### Test Case 4: Bad Id #2

*Input*

```
floatation
```

*Output (Tokens & Lexer Error)*

```
[FLOAT : float] [ID : tion] 
line 1:5 rule ID failed predicate: {!keyword}?
```

#### Test Case 5: Non-ID Rules

*Input*

```
int x
float 3 float 4 float 5
5 a 6 b 7 int 8 d
```

*Output (Tokens)*

```
[INT : int] [ID : x] 
[FLOAT : float] [NUMBER : 3] [FLOAT : float] [NUMBER : 4] [FLOAT : float] [NUMBER : 5] 
[NUMBER : 5] [ID : a] [NUMBER : 6] [ID : b] [NUMBER : 7] [INT : int] [NUMBER : 8] [ID : d]
```

Comment: Shouldn't nextToken only call super.nextToken if the token queue is empty?  That should solve the problem of normal tokens disappearing.

Comment: @TroyDaniels `super.nextToken` manages the call to the lexer rules. If it isn't called, `tokenQueue` won't get populated and `nextToken` won't have anything to return.

Comment: @TroyDaniels I updated the grammar (and added a test case) to handle other lexer rules: `nextToken` only draws tokens from `tokenQueue`, `emit(int, int)` calls `emit(Token)`, and `emit(Token)` is overridden to push all tokens into the queue. Not as bad as I thought it would be, but give it a try in case I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an almost-all-grammar solution for ANTLR 4 (only requires one small predicate in the target language):

```
lexer grammar PackedKeywords;

INT : 'int' -> pushMode(Keywords);
FLOAT : 'float' -> pushMode(Keywords);

fragment ID_CHAR : [a-z];
ID_START : ID_CHAR {Character.isLetter(_input.LA(1))}? -> more, pushMode(Identifier);
ID : ID_CHAR;

// these are the other tokens in the grammar
WS : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
Newline : '\r' '\n'? | '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN);

// The Keywords mode duplicates the default mode, except it replaces ID
// with InvalidKeyword. You can handle InvalidKeyword tokens in whatever way
// suits you best.
mode Keywords;

    Keywords_INT : INT -> type(INT);
    Keywords_FLOAT : FLOAT -> type(FLOAT);
    InvalidKeyword : ID_CHAR;
    // must include every token which can follow the Keywords mode
    Keywords_WS : WS -> type(WS), channel(HIDDEN), popMode;
    Keywords_Newline : Newline -> type(Newline), channel(HIDDEN), popMode;

// The Identifier mode is only entered if we know the current token is an
// identifier with >1 characters and which doesn't start with a keyword. This is
// essentially the default mode without keywords.
mode Identifier;

    Identifier_ID : ID_CHAR+ -> type(ID);
    // must include every token which can follow the Identifiers mode
    Identifier_WS : WS -> type(WS), channel(HIDDEN), popMode;
    Identifier_Newline : Newline -> type(Newline), channel(HIDDEN), popMode;
```

This grammar also works in the ANTLRWorks 2 lexer interpreter (coming soon!) for everything except single-character identifiers. Since the lexer interpreter can't evaluate the predicate in `ID_START`, an input like `a<space>` will (in the interpreter) produce a single token with text `a<space>` of type `WS` on the `HIDDEN` channel.

Comment: The docs say modes are only available for lexer only grammers.  If I want this to be available for a combined grammer do I need to make separate lexer and parser grammers and bridge them in the calling app?

p.s. Why lexer only?

Comment: What does the 'more' in the rewrite do? (link to doc?)

Comment: The `more` command says the text matched for the current token isn't a complete token, so try to match another token and combine the two for the result.